# Can I make a hostile Iron Golem less overpowered?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a minigame in Minecraft for my server which requires a lot of command blocks. There is a boss in the game that I summoned using:

```
/summon VillagerGolem ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Creeper",Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Fuse:32767,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}]}
```

The VillagerGolem is being controlled by a creeper and therefore will follow the player but not attack, but I sorted that out. I would like to give this mob a maximum speed and maximum damage as it is currently a little overpowered (the golem moves super fast and nearly one shot kills, which is too powerful along with the zombies I already have).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the iron golem's `generic.movementSpeed` attribute to a more desirable value.

However, the attack damage of iron golems is hard-coded and cannot be changed via commands. The most you could do is set `PlayerCreated` to 1 to prevent it from attacking players:

```
/summon VillagerGolem ~ ~1 ~ {Tags:["hostile_golem"],Attributes:[{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0.1}],PlayerCreated:1b,Passengers:[{id:"Creeper",Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Fuse:32767,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}]}
```

And use smoke and mirrors to attack the player (such as running a `/effect` command at the iron golem to apply Instant Damage to nearby players):

```
/execute @e[type=VillagerGolem,tag=hostile_golem] ~ ~ ~ /effect @a[r=3] minecraft:instant_damage
```

Comment: I have inputed the instant damage and i guess the Golem will be a fair fight at such a slow speed! Thanks!!!